# Getting url.split is not a function at getFilenameFromURLin Filepond and React-Filepond

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am getting the error above when uploading some of the files in my system... Below is the component using Filepond and React

```
const MultipleImages = ({multipleFiles,setMultipleFiles,name,maxNumber})=>{
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  return (
    <div style={{width: '95%'}}>
      <FilePond
        ref={ref}
        files={multipleFiles}
        maxFiles={maxNumber}
        allowMultiple={maxNumber > 1 ? true : false}
        fileValidateTypeLabelExpectedTypes="Invalid File Type"
        imagePreviewMaxFileSize='3MB'
        imagePreviewTransparencyIndicator="gray"
        labelIdle={`Drag & drop your ${name} or <span class="filepond--label-action"> Browse </span>`}
        acceptedFileTypes={[ 'image/png','image/jpeg']}
        onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
          setMultipleFiles(fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file))
        }}
      />
    </div> 
  );
};
```

Anyone else come across this and if so how can I solve it ?

EDIT : It works sometimes and stops at times

Comment: Not sure, maybe setMultipleFiles updates the state in some which that causes `multipleFiles` to have incorrect values?